# How to find the maximum area of a quadrilateral, when three of the sides add up to 24?

Tags: calculus, geometry, lagrange-multiplier, quadrilateral

If there's a quadrilateral ABCD, and the sides AB + BC + CD add up to 24, how can I find the maximum area of the quadrilateral formed, what length should the four sides of the quadrilateral be, and what should the interior angles be?

I think Lagrange multiplier needs to be used for such a case, but I'm not sure how to start. I think the constraint will be `x + y + z = 24`, but I'm not sure how to represent the area function. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Theres a variant of herons formula for quadrilateral area that uses the 4 sides and sum of opposite angles. Could be helpful here.

Comment: One way to satisfy the constraint is a square with side lengths of 8.  This isn't necessarily the *best* solution, but it does tell us that we need an area of *at least* 64.

Answer (score 3):

Reflect the quadrilateral across the fourth side to produce a hexagon with perimeter $48$. Of all hexagons with a given perimeter, the one with the greatest area is the regular hexagon ([proof](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/the-sagacity-of-circles-a-history-of-the-isoperimetric-problem-the-work-of-zenodorus)). So the maximum area of the hexagon is $96\sqrt3$, and so the maximum area of the quadrilateral is $48\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the four sides of the quadrilateral by $w = DA$, $x = AB$, $y = BC$, $z = CD$.

Let $d = AC$ be the length of one diagonal.  This splits the quadrilateral into two triangles, $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ACD$.

Use Heron's formula to find the area of the two triangles.

$$A = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(x + y + d)(-x + y + d)(x - y + d)(x + y - d)} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(w + z + d)(-w + z + d)(w - z + d)(w + z - d)}$$

But we're given that $x + y + z = 24$, so:

$$A = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(x + y + d)(-x + y + d)(x - y + d)(x + y - d)} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(w + z + (24 - x - y))(-w + (24 - x - y) + d)(w - (24 - x - y) + d)(w + (24 - x - y) - d)}$$

This gives us a formula for the area in terms of three sides of the quadrilateral ($w$, $x$, and $y$) and the diagonal $d$.  Some work will needed to be done to find the maximum, but at least now we know *what* to maximize.

Comment: Thanks for this! If the area function is A(w, x, y, d) but the constraint is g(x, y, z), isn't this unsolvable using Lagrange since the area function involves 2 unknowns that the constraint doesn't have, and the constraint involves 1 unknown the area function doesn't?